# Indoor based intrusion detection

Tags: opencv, intrusion-detection

Iam working on a indoor based intrusion detection on continous image dump  implementation using opencv.
I have to detect an intrusion in the perimeter set by the user.I have implemented the ui for user to set the perimeter(simple rectangle drawn by user) marked as regionofinterest
As of now iam using **backgroundsubtractormog2** for getting a foreground mask of the continous images.Are there any other good models to do this task? and how would i use the generated foreground masks to further declare that an intrusion has taken place or something happened i.e., how to automatically detect the objects which got intruded ?please help im a beginner in this area

Comment: is there any reason the mog2 subtractor doesn't fulfill your needs that would make you search for alternatives?  And what do you mean by detect the objects which got intruded, isn't the only "intrude-able" object the perimeter that the user set?

Comment: i wanted to eliminate noise from light variations and others and what i meant by detect the objects which got intruded is after i get the foreground mask how should i identify the regions of foreground and mark them.Any ways i was able to do those things with little noise using thresholds on contours detected.